# Why does the input boxes clear immediately after an onclick event

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a fill button that will fill the input values with the a default. When I go to click the fill button the defaults shows up for 2 seconds and then disappears. How do I get the information to stay without it clearing itself.

---

```
var enter, replace, FirstName, Telephone, email, BithDate, LastName, ZipCode, SS, Cash;

window.onload = function() {
  //calls the functions when buttons clicked
  replace = document.getElementById("fill");
  replace.addEventListener("click", filler);

  enter = document.getElementById("enter");
  enter.addEventListener("click", calculate);
  var clear = document.getElementById("clear");
  clear.addEventListener("click", clear);
}

function filler() {
  //list the default values to fill when the fill button is clicked
  FirstName = document.getElementById("FirstName").value = "Jane";
  Telephone = document.getElementById("tel").value = "888-777-9999";
  email = document.getElementById("email").value = "JaneDoe@example.com";
  BithDate = document.getElementById("birth").value = "2017";
  LastName = document.getElementById("LastName").value = "Doe";
  ZipCode = document.getElementById("zip").value = "12345";
  SS = document.getElementById("SocSec").value = "123-45-6789";
  Cash = document.getElementById("income").value = "123456";
}

function clear() {
  //clears the form and resets it to the default
  document.getElementById("form").reset();
}
```

Comment: please add html, or even better if you post your example on plunker or jsfiddle or somewhere else

Comment: Are you  sure `filler()` function is working ? variable declaration was wrong  **`"message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null",`**

Comment: Also seems to be missing calculate function. Posting the HTML would also be helpful.

Comment: When something shows up in a form when clicking a button, and then quickly disappears, odds are that you're submitting the form. However without your HTML and a [mcve] we can't be sure

Comment: Sounds like default button action is occurring - return false or event.preventDefault.

Answer (score 0):

You named your local variable for the clear button "clear" which shadows the global clear function, so clear.addEventListener("click", clear); doesn't work.  Try renaming the local variable to something like clearBtn.